# Raspberry Pi does not start up, green LED flashes 2 times

Tags: boot-issues

So I got a Raspberry Pi  B+ and it worked very well. Some day something happened and the microSD was broken. I checked it using `badblocks`. Now I got a new microSD and wanted to rearrange my structure but the pi won't boot at all. Everytime I connect it with the power supply the green LED just blinks 2 times and thats it, constant red and no signal. I tested this with all cables besides the power supply disconnected and even switched the power supply several times.
I really don't know what to do.

Is my pi broken?

Comment: 2 blinks is actually good; none would mean it can't read the card at all, and more than two would mean there's something wrong with firmware, etc. on the card.  I have been confused this way before after thinking I fried it -- I presume you've tried this with a monitor plugged in?  Is there no output at all?  Make sure you have `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` in `config.txt`.

Comment: No input at all, not even a `LAN`-cable nor `HDMI` nor `VGA`. I wrote a new downloaded `Raspbian` image to the file and even tried older versions that worked before with the same microSD type.
I wish it would blink more, as those patterns are well documented but I cannot find any documentation for 2 blinks, so I don't know whats wrong. :(

Comment: 2 blinks is what it does normally, and it will not blink at all if you remove the SD card.  But I have not found documentation for *exactly* what it means either.  Did you drop it?

Comment: No, there was no drop or anything like that. It was lying in a box for about 2 weeks working and then magically it stopped and here we are.

Comment: What about the LAN lights?  If those go up, it's established a low level ethernet connection, meaning the kernel is running (this does not mean it's actually connected to an IP network tho).

Comment: Its just `ACT` flashing 2 times on connection and the `PWR` without any flickering.

Comment: You have my sympathy ;|

Comment: So we can assume that it's broken? "._.
Then the reason must be the power supply.

Comment: Might be possible.  Some percentage of them must break at some point, nothing is perfect.

Comment: any USB devices attached? if so power off unplug and try again.

Comment: have you tried to re-image your new microsd?

Comment: @rob: No, just the power supply.

Comment: @geoffmcc: Sure I tried, I even used older images just to see if it works with them.

Comment: @Nacl, are you using Raspbian, noobs or another distro. How are you writing the image, are you in Windows or Linux when you do it?

Comment: @geoffmcc: I'm using Raspbian and I write the image using `dd if=[raspbian name].img of=/dev/mmcblk0 count=1M`

Comment: Try this: but I'm not sure if order maters. This is how I do it - dd bs=4M if=raspbianname.img of=/dev/mmcblk0. The only other thing I can think of is if this don't work try noobs (assuming you downloaded rsspbian image again to be sure was full download)

Comment: Also the dd command I provided came from http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to put in answer form. Per official raspberry pi site, the dd command should be

```
 dd bs=4M if=2014-09-09-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/mmcblk0
```

Edit: obviously changing image name to that of your image.

Comment: so `bs=4M` is needed...

Comment: But you got it working though right?

Comment: yes it works now. Adding `bs=4M` fixed it

Comment: Okay cool. I read your comment wrong at first and thought you said bs=4 wasnt needed. Glad your up and running..... If you have a USB drive to spare, I would move file system to USB so it will perform better and not burn out your SD card. If interested check out http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=44177 but powered drives work better than thumb drives. Plus you can over clock to turbo and not worry about slow SD read/write speeds giving you issues